# How to see if a GitHub issue has a pull request using API?

Tags: github, github-api

I like to show a list of issues and also indicate which of the issues has a pull request attached to it, all using the API

So I get the list of issues using:
https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/

but how can I detect if an issue has a pull request?

Using the web interface I can see on the issue UI if a issue has a pull request, but I can't seem to see that using the API

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/ Also, from the page you link: *"If an issue is a pull request, the object will include a `pull_request` key."* Seems like you should be able to puzzle it out.

Comment: But that's only if the issue IS a pull request

Comment: Yes, and pull request resources contain links to the related issue. Read the docs!

Answer (score 2):

I emailed the GitHub support and currently this information is not exposed using the API.

So currently it's not possible to see if an issue has a pull request attached to it